# About solving a first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following question which I cannot find a solution

Find a function $g$ verifying:

$$(x-f(x))g′(x)=g(x)$$

where $f$ is a given function defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: It's separable ...write $$\int \frac {dg}g=\int \frac {dx}{x-f(x)}$$

Comment: @Isham: Yes. It is the case.

Comment: Can you solve it ? DER

Comment: @Isham: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int\frac{dg}{g}=\int\frac{dx}{x-f}$$
$$\ln|g|=\int\frac{dx}{x-f}$$
$$g=e^{\int\frac{dx}{x-f}}$$
Badda boom badda bing you have your solution. Keep in mind that $\int\frac{dx}{x-f}$ may not have an elementary form depending on your choice of $f$.